# How to cancel Wordpress http requests of images?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

When my website first loads, it gives me 37 errors most of them saying :"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". These images aren't found on the server for some reason and as a result, my website loads very slowly. What should I do ? 
To my experience, I either should provide the missing images (although they aren't used on the website) or remove the code that is making those requests to the server. But how can I find the img tags from the html or background images from CSS and remove them? I am new to wordpress so your help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove img from css then please go to css path and find all background-image then remove this line.
You will be able to find css file in your template folder.

If you want to remove images from HTML for that after login you need edit that page/post on which you are getting missing error image.